# Selector: "<item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute"

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I've got the following button:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/searchCompaniesButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/company_icon"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/next_icon_big"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:backgroud="@drawable/transparent_button_selector"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/searchCompanies" />
```

`transparent_button_selector` is `transparent_button_selector.xml` in /drawable-ldpi folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/lightGrey"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/veryLightGrey"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@null" />
</selector>
```

Also I've got a `colors.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="lightGrey">#3d3d3d</color>
  <color name="veryLightGrey">#4d4d4d</color>
</resources>
```

But when I run my app, log will say:

> 'item' tag requires a 'drawable' attribute"

What the hell? I know there are few similar questions, but answers are not helpful. I tried:

- Restarting Eclipse
- Cleaning projects
- Running app at real device(crush)

Comment: Try using transparent color instead of null.

Comment: Why don't you just delete that empty item?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Replace this:

```
 <item android:drawable="@null" />
```

with:

```
<item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
```

and add transparent color in your color file with code: #00000000

Comment: just for correctness:
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"  />

Answer (score 0):

The drawable attribute always takes @drawable.i.e
you have to replace

```
<item android:drawable="@color/..."
      android:state_pressed="true" />
```

with

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/..."
      android:state_pressed="true" />
```

Use this,

```
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/selected_state" />
```

Then make a shape in drawable folder with name "selected_state" like this.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:shape="rectangle">
       <solid android:color="@color/lightGrey" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `android:background` attribute is misspelled:

android:backgroud="@drawable/transparent_button_selector"

The letter 'n' is missing in 'backgrou**n**d'

Answer (score 0):

If a `selector` is used to show which items in a list are currently picked then the best answer simply:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/activated_color"  android:state_activated="true"/>
</selector>
```

Picked items are then determined by the `isActivated` state if the view.

Why is a transparent background better than the more more direct statement of "no background"?